# issue redirecting http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to enforce https for all traffic and I've tried to add the following lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`
```

The issue is that the current .htaccess file already has the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

I combined both as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working out. I'm getting a redirect loop error... Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why explain what "creases to work" actually means and show your final attempt that did not work as you hoped.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not readable. There is an edit botton below your question. Use it.

Comment: @arkascha, I've edited the main post as the comment rendered it unreadable. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Why are you combining it like that? It makes no sense...

Comment: I agree with @MikeRockett here: why do you try to combine the https-off condition with the others for rewriting? Don't! Keep things separate. Externally rewrite http requests to http unconditionally. Then, for the next incoming https request apply your existing routing rewrites. I am also confused by the code snippets you now posted with your update of the question. It appears that you already have http to https rewriting in the second snippet which you say is "the current .htaccess file". That looks fine for me, so what is the issue? Does it _not_ redirect http requests to the https server?

Comment: sorry @arkascha, I'm a rookie at this. I've edited the second snippet as it already included one version of the merged rules. 
I've tried multiples ways to combine this and it doesn't work. What do you mean I need to rewrite http to https externally? On httpd.config file, for example, or on the same .htacess file?

Comment: 1. externally rewriting means to send a redirection header to the client instead of rewriting internally, which makes absolutely no sense for an http to https redirection. You do that by using the flags `[L,R=301]` in the rule. See the documentation for what that means exactly and examples.

Comment: 2. if you actually have access to the http servers host configuration, then you should keep all rules in there instead of using .htaccess style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow the server down for nothing. They are only offered as a last option for those _not_ having access to the http servers configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```